# Using static classes as namespaces

Tags: c#, c++, object-oriented, static-typing, namespace

I have seen other developers using static classes as namespaces

```
public static class CategoryA
{
    public class Item1
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
    }
    public class Item2
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
    }
}

public static class CategoryB
{
    public class Item3
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
    }
    public class Item4
    {
        public void DoSomething() { }
    }
}
```

To instantiate the inner classes, it will look like the following

```
CategoryA.Item1 item = new CategoryA.Item1();
```

The rationale is that namespaces can be hidden by using the "using" keyword. But by using the static classes, the outer-layer class names have to be specified, which effectively preserves the namespaces.

Microsoft advises against that in [the guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdz1bea9%28VS.71%29.aspx). I personally think it impacts the readability. What are your thoughts?

Comment: It's up to the implementer whether they need the namespaces present in the implementation. Why would you force the use of the namespaces (and fake namespaces at that) on them?

Comment: May be for grouping purposes? Like there are a lot sub classes and by grouping the sub classes to static classes. That make the intension clear?

Comment: Would putting the sub classes in a sub-namespace not also make the intention clear? Also, this is the type of problem solved by documentation.

Answer (score 16):

Using static classes as namespaces defies the purpose of having namespaces.

The key difference is here:

If you define `CategoryA`, `CategoryB<` as namespaces, and when application uses two namespaces :

```
CategoryA::Item1 item = new CategoryA::Item1(); 
CategoryB::Item1 item = new CategoryB::Item1();
```

Here if the `CategoryA` or `CategoryB` is a static class rather than namespace, the usage for the application is almost same as described above.

However, if you define it as a namespace and application uses only 1 namespace (doesn't include `CategoryB`), in that case application can actually use following

```
using namespace CategoryA; 
Item1 item = new Item1();
```

But had you define `CategoryA` as a static class the above is undefined! 
One is forced to write `CategoryA.something` every time.

Namespaces should be used to avoid naming conflicts whereas class hierarchy should be used when class grouping has some relevance to the system model.

Comment: Also, if someone wants to not use namespaces, even using classes the can: `using Item1 = CategoryA.Item1` (i think that works for nested classes as it does for namespaces)

Comment: In C++, [ADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) does not work with class scope; it works with namespace scope. So in C++, the namespace isn't only natural choice, but *correct* and *idiomatic* choice **also**.

Comment: I think it's OP's intention to avoid hiding namespace by the using keyword. He wants to force users to writie it every time. Maybe his namespace is like `var s = new HideMe.MyPhoneNumberIs12345678.TheRealUsefulClass()`

Answer (score 5):

Whatever is going on here certainly isn't idiomatic C# code.

Maybe these others are trying to implement the module pattern - this would let you have functions, actions and so on as well as classes in the 'namespace' (i.e. static class in this case)?

Comment: I agree, looks weird.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, every class should be in a namespace, so your example would actually more be like:

```
SomeNamespace.CategoryA.Item1 item = new SomeNamespace.CategoryA.Item1();
```

That said, I see no benefit of this kind of code gymnastics when you can just as well define such a namespace:

```
namespace SomeNamespace.CategoryA { ... }
```

If you are maybe some day thinking of storing some static methods on upper class level, this could make sense, but still is not what C# creators have in mind, and might just make it less readable to others — I would waste a lot of time thinking WHY you did this, and thinking if I am missing some source file that would provide explanations.

Comment: So why are enums the [exception to the rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx)?

Comment: That is a different question :) But I would still not define a static class just in order to define enums in it.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces in Java, JavaScript and .NET related aren't complete, and only allow to store classes, but other stuff like constants or global methods, don't.

Many developers use the "static classes" or "static methods" tricks, even if some people don't recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but one very valid reason to use a class as a namespace (a non-static one at that) is that C# does not support the definition of parametric or generic namespaces.  I've written up a blog post on this very topic [here: http://tyreejackson.com/generics-net-part5-generic-namespaces/](http://tyreejackson.com/generics-net-part5-generic-namespaces/).

The gist of it is, when using generics to abstract huge swaths of boilerplate code, it is sometimes necessary to share multiple generic parameters between related classes and interfaces.  The conventional way to do this would be to redefine the generic parameters, constraints and all in each interface and class signature.  Over time this can lead to a proliferation of parameters and constraints not to mention constantly having to qualify the related types by forwarding the type parameters from one type to the type arguments of the related type.

Using an outer Generic class and nesting the related types within can dramatically DRY up the code and simplify its abstraction.  One can then derive the parametric namespace class with a concrete implementation that supplies all of the concrete details.

Here is a trivial example:

```
public  class   Entity
                <
                    TEntity, 
                    TDataObject, 
                    TDataObjectList, 
                    TIBusiness, 
                    TIDataAccess, 
                    TIdKey
                >
        where   TEntity         : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TDataObjectList, TIBusiness, TIDataAccess, TIdKey>, subclassed
        where   TDataObject     : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TDataObjectList, TIBusiness, TIDataAccess, TIdKey>.BaseDataObject, subclassed
        where   TDataObjectList : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TDataObjectList, TIBusiness, TIDataAccess, TIdKey>.BaseDataObjectList, subclassed
        where   TIBusiness      : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TDataObjectList, TIBusiness, TIDataAccess, TIdKey>.IBaseBusiness
        where   TIDataAccess    : Entity<TEntity, TDataObject, TDataObjectList, TIBusiness, TIDataAccess, TIdKey>.IBaseDataAccess
{

    public class    BaseDataObject
    {
        public TIdKey Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseDataObjectList : Collection<TDataObject> {}

    public interface IBaseBusiness
    {

        TDataObject     LoadById(TIdKey id);
        TDataObjectList LoadAll();
        void            Save(TDataObject item);
        void            Save(TDataObjectList items);
        void            DeleteById(TIdKey id);
        bool            Validate(TDataObject item);
        bool            Validate(TDataObjectList items);

    }

    public interface IBaseDataAccess
    {

        TDataObject     LoadById(TIdKey id);
        TDataObjectList LoadAll();
        void            Save(TDataObject item);
        void            Save(TDataObjectList items);
        void            DeleteById(TIdKey id);

    }

}
```

Used like this:

```
public  class   User 
:
                Entity
                <
                    User, 
                    User.DataObject, 
                    User.DataObjectList, 
                    User.IBusiness, 
                    User.IDataAccess, 
                    Guid
                >
{
    public class DataObject : BaseDataObject
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataObjectList : BaseDataObjectList {}

    public interface IBusiness : IBaseBusiness
    {
        void DeactivateUserById(Guid id);
    }

    public interface IDataAcccess : IBaseDataAccess {}
}
```

Consume the derivatives like this:

```
public class EntityConsumer
{
    private User.IBusiness       userBusiness;
    private Permission.IBusiness permissionBusiness;

    public EntityConsumer(User.IBusiness userBusiness, Permission.IBusiness permissionBusiness) { /* assign dependencies */ }

    public void ConsumeEntities()
    {
        var users       = new User.DataObjectList();
        var permissions = this.permissionBusiness.LoadAll();

        users.Add
        (new User.DataObject()
        {
            // Assign property values
        });

        this.userBusiness.Save(users);

    }
}
```

The benefit to writing the types this way is added type safety and less casting of types in the abstract classes.  Its the equivalent of `ArrayList` vs `List<T>` on a larger scale.